# Can't send POST JsonObjectRequest using volley

Tags: android, node.js, android-volley

I just want to send `POST` request using volley but on the server side I get nothing:

Here's my code :

**ANDROID**

```
JsonObjectRequest sr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response){

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws 
         AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("email",email.getText().toString());
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).add(sr);
```

**NODE**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express() ; 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') ; 


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()) ; 

app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
//email and passwords

console.log(req.body);
})

app.listen(80);
```

and this is the result : `{}`

However when I use `StringRequest` all things go correctly but when I use `JsonObjectRequest` seems `node.js` can not read body of the incoming request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in null for the third parameter of JsonObjectRequest.

"Null is allowed and indicates no parameters will be posted along with request."
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/43950676303ff68b23a8b469d6a534ccd1e08cfc/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java#40

Pass a JSONObject there instead if you want to use JsonObjectRequest.

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("email", "email@email.com");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);

JsonObjectRequest sr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, json, ...)
queue.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).add(sr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I cant pass a JsonObjectRequest into the constructor, would you edit your answer and include the code based on my code above.

Comment: please read carefully, i mentioned JSONObject into JsonObjectRequest

Comment: Thanks it works! so we don't need to override the getParams method ? the way we do for StringRequest

Comment: In the base class, Request, "getParams()" get's called from "getBody()". In JsonRequest, it overrides "getBody()" and use its own implementation of getting the body and doesn't use getParams(). Thus you don't need to override getParams() when using JsonObjectRequest (which is a subclass of JsonRequest).